# Cannot see Incoming E-mail setting options under communication tab for list/library

Tags: 2013, permissions, custom-list, incoming-email

I am not able to see Incoming e-mail settings options under communication tab for Custom list? why is this so? I am using SharePoint server 2013.

Do I have to activate any feature to see it? or have any special permissions right now i am a site collection administration for the site.

Comment: what is version of sharepoint?

Comment: @Waqas Sorry, I could see "Incoming e-mail settings" for Document library but not for Custom list under Communication tab. I am using SharePoint Server 2013.

Comment: did you configure the incoming email setting for the sharepoint farm?

Comment: Yes, I did configure Incoming email settings in Central Administration and AD and Exchange server.(Is it mandatory to configure them to view the option under list settings?)

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box SharePoint only supports receiving email to specific types of lists and libraries. For instance, you can receive email on an Announcements list, calendar list,discussion board and libraries. However, you cannot receive email on custom lists.

As a workaround, either you use an announcement list or library and customize it according to your need.

If you are developer then check this custom solution.[Enable Incoming emails on a Custom SharePoint List](https://jasear.wordpress.com/2010/11/11/enable-incoming-emails-on-a-custom-sharepoint-list/)

[Enabling Incoming Email Setting For Custom Generic List in SharePoint](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/prasham/enabling-incoming-email-setting-for-custom-generic-list-in-s/)